# How to configure systemjs.config.js to use relative path in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, systemjs

I have just started an ASP.NET MVC web application which uses Angular for its UI components.  Plumbed the necessary config files into my project (e.g. `package.json` and `systemjs.config.js`).  Create a test page `Index.cshtml` to test out `app.component.ts` template.  The application is working when running under my localhost.  I can see the page rendering the custom tag `<user-app>` from the template.

However, the issue is that when I deploy the web application into IIS (dev server),  I have encountered the following `HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier)`.

[image]

This is the app `package.json` file

```
    {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

The app `systemjs.config.js` file

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
                //meta: {
                //    './*.js': {
                //        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                //    }
                //},
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

The `app.component.ts` file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
                <div class='container-fluid'>
                    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                        <li>
                            <a [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class='container'>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

The `main.ts` file

```
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The `app.module.ts` file

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and app page `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Control Systems Management</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        //SystemJS.config({
        //    baseURL: '.'
        //});

        System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Also in IIS, I have configured an application and named it `ControlSystem` under `Default Web Site`.  Looking at the `http error`, the server didn't find `main.js` because it is suppose to be a relative path (eg. `http://myDomain/controlsystem/app/main.js`).  I tried several approach to configure `systemjs.config.js` but it didn't worked out.

This is the folder structure of `.ts` files inside my visual studio project

[image]

I did some research online on how to resolve such issue, but I couldn't find similar one.  If there is, please direct me to such reference.

I'm pretty new to Angular and wading online to learn all these related configuration settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my own implementation, I had these kind of issue as well. It would work if I put direct paths but it broke within where I used imports, it also broke within where I used relative paths to my web api endpoints. I solved it by adding the following line before the line with the `paths` in `systemjs.config.js`: `baseURL: '/',`

Comment: @I.R.R. thanks for your comment.  So, I also add the following line in `systemjs.config.js` like `System.config({baseURL: '/', paths: { ... }})` but still I got an error when I check the browser's console saying `Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://mydomain/app/main.js`  What do you mean by "It would work if I put direct paths"?

Comment: As in I didn't put (.) or (..) or (~) before the paths, but that's just asking for trouble as it made other things break. Anyway, I don't know if you've done this, but this also helped me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2010/05/26/how-extensionless-urls-are-handled-by-asp-net-v4/

Comment: @I.R.R. Thanks for sharing the link.  Unfortunately, it didn't helped me :(

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of other developers who may encounter this issue. Luckily, I figured out the solution.

It's quite a simple solution though. In `_Layout.cshtml`, inside `<head>` section, put `<base href="~/" />` as the first element.

According to this documentation https://angular.io/guide/router, the `<base href="/">` tells Angular router what is the static part of the URL. The router then only modifies the remaining part of the URL.  In my case I had to put `~` "tilde" to make it relative.

Hope this helps.